# In a triangle $ABC$, prove that $\sin A \times \cos A + 2 \cos B \times \cos C \leq 1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

I've stumbled upon an exercise I don't really know how to handle. It's the following inequality:

If $A, B$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle, prove $$\sin A \times \cos A + 2 \cos B \times \cos C \leq 1.$$

I've tried using triangle relations with its corresponding angles and other trigonometric formulas to reduce the problem to a simpler relation, but I've only made it worse so far.

Any help or suggestions? Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here's an admittedly rather long but very helpful tutorial on using MathJax formatting to make the mathematics in your questions easier for everyone (including you, likely) to read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. Sorry for being careless about this!

Comment: It's okay, I appreciate that you're making an effort to learn! (That's more than can be said for some users)

Answer (score 0):

using the formulas
$$S=\frac{bc}{2}\sin(A)$$
and
$$\cos(A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$ ect.
you will have $$\frac{2A}{bc}\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}+2\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}\le 1$$
and $$S=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$ where $$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$
we get $$4a^2(b^2+c^2-a^2)S\le bc(4a^2bc-2(a^2+c^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2))$$
now i would consider the cases:
$$b^2+c^2=a^2$$
$$b^2+c^2<a^2$$
$$b^2+c^2>a^2$$
the first case gives us $$0\le (b-c)^2$$ which is true.